Why does my WPF button not show the text when I apply a template to it?
I'm trying to learn WPF from an old book (Beginning Visual C# 2010). I've tried to replicate the example that they provided (and it does look horrid), but for some reason, the text does not display on the button.
The example code is:
<Window x:Class="BadButtonTraining.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BadButtonTraining"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Nastsy Button" Height="150" Width="550">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Button Margin="20" Click="Button_Click" FontFamily="arial" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
            Would anyone use a button like this?
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Purple" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Azure" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Purple" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="50" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Yellow" />
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Red" />
                                                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Height="50">
                                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Yellow" />
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Red" />
                                                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                                    </Ellipse>
                                    <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Height="50">
                                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Yellow" />
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Red" />
                                                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                                    </Ellipse>
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="20,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Which (for me) produces a horrid button shading from yellow to red, with circles on each side, but I can't see the text for the button.
`Horrid button with radial shading, but the text not displaying
If I remove the <Setter Property="Template"> block (to give the following code), I get a button with the "Would anyone use a button like this?" text visible (admittedly with that horrid linear gradient from white to purple):
<Window x:Class="BadButtonTraining.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BadButtonTraining"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Nastsy Button" Height="150" Width="550">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Button Margin="20" Click="Button_Click" FontFamily="arial" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
            Would anyone use a button like this?
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Purple" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Azure" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Purple" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

`Rectangular button with text with a horrid gradient on it
I'm using .NET Framework 4.8.1.

There is a ContentPresenter, in the Setter and I've tried putting it in a few different locations, but to no benefit.
I've tried putting the text after the template, but had no effect.
I've tried putting the text into a Content property, but again no effect.

I have noticed that sometimes the text appears on-top of the first circle, but behind all the other shapes. Sometimes, it doesn't show above any of them.
Please note that I've removed any URLs from the Window tag so that this don't get mistaken for spam.

Add Grid.ColumnSpan="3" to ContentPresenter. The Grid is divided to 3 columns and without specifying ColumnSpan, ContentPresenter will span only the left one.

Bind the Button's content to the ContentPresenter with a TemplateBinding
<ContentPresenter 
    Margin="20,0"
    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />


Didn't help. It was the column span that fixed it.
I've added in the Content property though, as it looks like a good idea to me.
